# Google Visualization ControlWrapper height

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Visualization to plot two charts, one with the central information, and another that I'm using as an overview. The `ControlWrapper` is used to control the range in the main chart.

[image]

```
function renderChart(data) {

    data = _data_as_array(data['history']);
    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
        $.merge([['Date', 'Infected', '1st Degree', '2nd Degree']], data),
    );

    var options = {
        hAxis: {textPosition: 'none', gridlines: { color: 'transparent' }, baselineColor: 'transparent'},
        vAxis: {textPosition: 'none', gridlines: { color: 'transparent' }, baselineColor: 'transparent'},
        legend: {position: 'none'},
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        series: {
            0: { color: '#6958E5' },
            1: { color: '#747171' },
            2: { color: '#EF8131' }
        },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'AreaChart',
        containerId: 'covidoff-chart',
        options: $.extend({
            chartArea: {
                width: '98%',
                height: '100%'
            }
        }, options)
    });

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'covidoff-chart-control',
        dataTable: data,
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0, // filter on dates
            ui: {
                chartOptions: {
                    chartArea: {
                        width: '98%',
                        height: '20'
                    }
                },
            },
        },
    });

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('covidoff-chart-container'));
    dashboard.bind([control], [chart]);
    dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

This is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="covidoff-chart-container" class="d-none">
    <div id="covidoff-chart"></div>
    <div id="covidoff-chart-control"></div>
    <div>a</div>
</div>
```

You can see in the picture above that there's a huge whitespace below the control. That space would be the default height for the control, and setting `options.ui.chartOptions.chartArea.height` seems to shrink the chart but not the area.

Inspecting the HTML, I see that the tool is injecting this style inline, and giving it a height to `200px`.

[image]

I'd assume it's reasonable to use CSS to change this, but since I'm not the one managing the elements I'm also thinking it break something, or not always work.

What's the correct way to properly set the height?

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: Want to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chartArea` is for the inner portion where the area lines are drawn,
for the overall height, use --> `options.ui.chartOptions.height`